# zope.schema fields reference manual

Tags: plone, zope

Is there anywhere human readable documentation for what fields zope.schema provides out of the box?

And because there probably isn't anything covering the whole zope.schema, what is the next best reference, excluding the source code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package includes full documentation built with Sphinx; the latest version is [published online at docs.zope.org](http://docs.zope.org/zope.schema/).

In addition, there is a [chapter on zope.schema](http://wiki.zope.org/zope3/schema.html) published on the Zope3 Wiki, as part of [Stephan Richter's Zope3 Book](http://wiki.zope.org/zope3/Zope3Book). The [PDF rendering of that chapter](http://wiki.zope.org/zope3/schema.pdf) is perhaps more readable.

Then there is Philipp von Weitershausen's *excellent* book [*Web Component development with Zope 3*](http://worldcookery.com/About.html), which covers zope.schema as well.

Comment: Do you think the chapter from the book could be contributed to zope.schema package documentation? It dearly needs something like that and the chapter seems to be an excellent source.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: You'd need to check with Stephan Richter, I guess.